# How can I create a join without sql code in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can't make a join in rails, I don't know what is wrong here. my classes are:

`class Serie < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :user_serie

 has_many :user, :through => :user_serie

end`

`class UserSerie < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :serie

 belongs_to :user

end`

and

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :user_serie

 has_many :serie, :through => :user_serie

end`

and the select is:
 `@series = Serie.all :joins => :user`

so the generated select is:

```
SELECT "series".* FROM "series" 
INNER JOIN "user_series" ON "series"."id" = "user_series"."serie_id" 
INNER JOIN "users" 
 ON 0 
 AND "users" 
 AND 'id' 
 AND "users"."id" 
 AND 0 
 AND "user_series" 
 AND 'user_id'
 AND "user_series"."user_id" 
 AND "users"."id" = "user_series"."user_id"
```

What can I do to make this select works?

I've tried to make the has_many with plural, but then I have this error: 
uninitialized constant Serie::UserSeries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong relations, should be:

```
class Serie < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :user_series
has_many :users, :through => :user_series
end

class UserSerie < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :serie
belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :user_series
has_many :series, :through => :user_series
end
```

When you get exception with uninitialized class, then use explicit :class_name like below:

```
class Serie < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :user_series, :class_name => "UserSerie" 
# or "::UserSerie", i'm not 100% sure which one, rather just as I wrote
has_many :users, :through => :user_series
end
```

Comment: It worked with the plural terms, but still the generated sql is that weird stuff..

Comment: I'm not sure why it is so ugly the sql, maybe you have some nasty gem in the Gemfile? No idea here, I would need some more info in another question. Give me a sign on that one, it is interesting.